# Pushing data across browsers (same session)

Tags: php, ajax

I've seen pages like facebook where, if you post a message in your newsfeed, it automatically pushes that across your browsers.  Or like on this page... if someone has answered a question while you are typing, a bar drops down.

Are they just calling AJAX requests every 30 seconds or whatever?  It seems like that would be a resource drain on your server.  Is there a way to push something at the browser instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 options here:

- Use the new (experimental) browser API (sockets)
- Long polling / comet
- Using / listening to cookies

---

### Long polling / comet example in PHP / AJAX

```
// PHP SIDE

$max_wait_time = 30; // at most, 30 seconds
$start_time = microtime(true);

while( $start_time - microtime(true) < $max_wait_time ){
    // ...check if something changed (eg, run an SQL query or something)
    if($something_changed){
        echo 'something changed';
        die;
    }
    // if the user did abort, terminate immediately
    if( connection_aborted() ) die;
    // sleep for one second. For faster responses, keep
    // splitting this suitably (eg, 0.5 of a second...)
    usleep(1000000);
}


// JS SIDE

var poll = function(){
    jQuery.get('the url', function(){
        poll();
    });
}

poll();
```

### Cookie example in PHP / JS (you need the jQuery cookie plugin)

```
<?php

    // PHP SIDE
    setcookie('test', mt_rand(0,100));

?><!-- HTML/JS SIDE -->

<a href="javascript:locaion.reload()">Rand!</a>

Rand=<span><?php echo $_COOKIE['test']; ?></span>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var oldrand = <?php echo $_COOKIE['test']; ?>;
    setInterval(function(){
        var newrand = jQuery.cookie('test');
        if( newrand!=oldrand ){
            jQuery('span').html(newrand);
            oldrand = newrand;
        }
    }, 500);

</script>
```

---

The cookie one is pretty good for several reasons:

- it is pretty fast (no AJAX calls)
- it is less resource intensive on both client and server side
- it consumes less bandwidth / network resources
- it is much easier to control

In some cases where cookies cannot work, I'd still advocate the use of cookies as a signal to run an AJAX call, hence you wouldn't need to run a lot of AJAX calls just to wait for a change to happen.

On the other hand, the cookie one won't work when the change is happening by a third party, eg, it won't be suitable at all for chat systems.

Answer (score 2):

Read into the differences between *push* and *pull* for more information:

In your example, the AJAX requests every 30 seconds would be a *pull* request - constantly asking the server if any updates are available, followed by a response.
You can set up a server/website to send *push* notifications to the client browser - whereby the client sits quietly, and the server sends the data/information to the client as soon as it is available (reducing network traffic etc.).

Push is much better in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you'd have to poll with a looping Ajax script. To keep resource drain down, you might want to send some kind of hash (the timestamp of the last news item for instance) so the server knows if the client is up to date. This way, it can instantly return if there's no changes to push.